# How can I create a Python wrapper around Perl code?

Tags: python, perl, rest, integration, wrapper

I'm hoping to write a Python wrapper around an existing Perl API for a site I'm intending to build using the RESTful web services framework. Has anyone been able to do this (build a Python-to-Perl wrapper) with much success?

I have seen the page here http://wiki.python.org/moin/IntegratingPythonWithOtherLanguages#Perl, which details a few available packages, but I wasn't sure if anyone had any experience with using these and if any is better than an other?

Any pros and cons please? :-D

Answer (score 2):

Use `subprocess`

```
subprocess.Popen( "perl some_code.pl" )
```

Works really well.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking that, but makes things a lot more difficult to maintain!

Comment: @Steve: How so?  The perl is untouched.  The Python invokes the perl script.  It's one line of code.  What is "difficult to maintain"?  Please be **specific** on the problems this will cause.

Comment: I'm creating a wrapper around a Perl API and not a specific Perl script, so using this method would mean having to create a wrapper script for each function in Perl and then call that using subprocess from Python. It would make more sense to do everything in Perl if that was the case! I was hoping to use Python and Django for the RESTful wsf, but I may have to use Perl and Catalyst? I'll update my post accordingly!

Comment: "create a wrapper script for each function in Perl"  Seems excessive.  Are wrappers really necessary?  Or can a single line of code be provided to perl.  We do this in Python:  `python -c 'import package; package.function(args)'` to provide one line of code and saving having to write a lot of wrappers.

Comment: I'll give this a try! It certainly seems my only option in the absence of a package to allow inline Perl code. That being said, the developers I am working with are going with Catalyst for this project, but I can use this method for some of my own work in the future :-)

Answer (score 1):

PyPerlish is no longer developed and Inline::Python is for using python code in perl, so... I'd go with PyPerl.

Comment: Yeah, from what I can tell they are all pretty much stagnant from a maintenance perspective. Having real trouble installing PyPerl on OS X! Appears as though openSUSE (11.4) has the most recent version at 1.0.1d, so might have to try installing on Linux instead!

Comment: @Steve: According to [this, search for 1.0.1d](http://blog.gmane.org/gmane.comp.web.zope.perl), I can only assume that 1.0.1c and 1.0.1d are the same, except for the setup script. So, you might want to try 1.0.1c on OS X.

Comment: Yeah, from what I can tell 1.0.1d runs perl Makefile.PL automatically for you! Not much of an issue to run it myself. I'll get 1.0.1c instead and have a try :)

Comment: Managed to find 1.0.1d with several patches from Mandriva, but can't get to compile currently - http://svn.mandriva.com/svn/packages/cooker/python-perlmodule/current/SOURCES/